# What flags do I need to pass to ditto to mimic the behavior of "right click -> Compress"?

Tags: macos, ditto

I'm writing a shell script that needs to compress a dir with the same options that are set from the Mac GUI when you do a "right click -> Compress".  From what I understand ditto is the right tool for the job, but what flags do I need to pass besides "-c"?  I've tried raw "-c" as well as "-c -k" and both give different results from the right click.

Comment: Could you explain in what way that annoys you the result obtained with "-c -k" is different from right click->Compress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to "man ditto",

> The command:

```
       ditto -c -k --sequesterRsrc --keepParent src_directory archive.zip
```

> will create a PKZip archive similarly to the Finder's Compress functionality.